# Define maximum number of revisions per post type?

Tags: revisions

How can I define the maximum number of [revisions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Revision_Management) on a per-post type basis?

For example posts have 3 max revisions where as pages have a max of 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong, but my first guess would be that this is not easily possible, because number of revisions gets saved into constant and does not seem hook-able.

From quick search relevant checks are in `wp_save_post_revision()` and it's very rigid.

Comment: What about remove_post_type_support() to remove support from built-in post types?

Comment: @QStudio that seems like a distinctly different question? Not sure on top of my head...

Comment: Right - jumping between question and found an answer to what I needed - but this is not the answer to this question - sorry!